# How to save the last serial value in Postgres?

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

This is how I do in SQL Server:

```
insert into users(name, password) values('admin', '1');
declare @id int;
set @id = @@identity;
insert into usersroles values(@id, 1);
insert into usersroles values(@id, 2);
```

`@@identity` *is in sql server the last inserted identity (serial)*

How to do the same in Postgres?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the RETURNING clause for INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO users (name, password) VALUES ('admin', '1') RETURNING id;
```

That will return one row which contains the assigned id.

Another option is to use the `currval` function after you insert into the users table:

```
SELECT currval('users_id_seq');
```

Answer (score 1):

From the intertubes:

```
  INSERT INTO Table1 (...)
    VALUES (...);

  GET DIAGNOSTICS res_oid = RESULT_OID;

  SELECT INTO ...
    FROM Table1 t
    WHERE t.oid = res_oid;
```